# Why does my definition for function read a number as if it is negative?

Tags: python, fibonacci

I have an issue with my code when defining a function. When giving an input number (defined by n), I want my code to define the Fibonacci series of this number. However, even if the number n is positive, the fibo function still reads the number as it is negative and prints 'None'. Why does it do that? Please find my code below:

```
def fibo(x):
    if x > 0: 
        if x <= 1:
            return x
        else:
            return(fibo(x-1) + fibo(x-2))
    elif x < 0:
       return None

n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    print(fibo(i))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you’re actually seeing something a bit different here. What happens if the argument to your function is 0? In that case, neither branch of the if/elif will execute, since zero is neither greater than nor less than zero. The effect of this is that the function finishes without executing a return statement, which is where the None is coming from.

To fix this, change the first condition in your if statement to read

```
if x >= 0:
```

As a note, since Python functions implicitly return None if you don’t explicitly return anything, you don’t actually need the elif here. Do you see why?

Hope this helps!